# Libcamera command not found after installing it

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-22.04

Having a terrible time with the raspi related problems. One of them concerning the libcamera. I have Ubuntu 22.04 64bit on my raspi and I have installed the libcamera package with the command sudo apt install libcamera_*. The problem is that whenever I run a command with libcamera it tells me command not found!!! Any solutions?!! The camera is detected and supported. Thanks in advance for your help.